# How can I show or hide some buttons depend on the user's rights, in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

With angularjs, we usually use plain HTML to write views. Now I have a question: how can I show or hide some buttons depend on the user's rights?

For example, current page is displaying an article. If the current user is the author or the article, or administrator, then "Delete" button will be displayed.

But since the view is plain HTML, how can I control it?

I can post an request to pass some data(e.g. current user id, article id) to server to check, but if there are many buttons, I need to request many times, which is not effective.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [ngShow directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow). I put together [a little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/Takey/1/), but the important bit is simply:

```
<button ng-show="user.id==post.postedby">Delete</button>
```

Comment: @Freewind : I thought you were looking at the most elegant solution for checking the user's rights!  As in, if the user is logged in , this information would be in the server ( not on the client! ), so I was actually looking for the most elegant solution for this.

Is there a solution which caters for not checking this each time on the server?

Comment: @ganaraj, Not sure if I understand the problem. Information about authentication and authorization can exist on the client side as well. The server has final say of course (the server will verify permissions when the user requests a deletion), but the client can still know who the current user is and what permissions they have in order to reflect that in the UI.

Comment: Yeah, it's OK if the client can manipulate things (eg in this example the client user could easily inspect element and make one of those hidden buttons be shown).  But the important thing is that even if this cheater client can edit the data on his own browser, the server would reject him (if auth was done right).  So it would be useless.