# Hide Delete User if user is logged AngularJS 8.2.14

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

Similar to [How can I show or hide some buttons depend on the user's rights, in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150106/how-can-i-show-or-hide-some-buttons-depend-on-the-users-rights-in-angularjs), how can I hide Delete button from User list if the user is logged?

**user.component.html** (ng-hide is not working, is it necessary to change to *ngHide?)

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="users" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> userId </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.userId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="accountId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> accountId </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.account.accountId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="accountName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> accountName </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.account.accountName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> userName </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.userName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="emailAddress">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> emailAddress </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.emailAddress}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="password">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> password </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.password}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="enabled">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> enabled </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.enabled}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="lastLogin">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> lastLogin </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.lastLogin}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><button ng-hide="user.userName==loginService.getUser()" class="btn btn-danger"  (click)="deleteUser(user)"> Delete user</button> </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientService, User} from "../service/httpclient.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-user",
  templateUrl: "./user.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./user.component.css"]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["userId", "accountId", "accountName", "userName", "emailAddress", "enabled", "lastLogin", "delete"];

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClientService
      .getUsers()
      .subscribe(response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response));
  }

  handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
    this.users = response;
  }

  deleteUser(user: User): void {
    this.httpClientService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      this.users = this.users.filter(u => u !== user);
    });
  }
}
```

**authentication.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class User {
  constructor(public status: string) {}
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}


// Provide username and password for authentication, and once authentication is successful,
// store JWT token in session
  authenticate(username, password) {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<any>('http://localhost:9898/authenticate', { username, password })
      .pipe(
        map(userData => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
          const tokenStr = 'Bearer ' + userData.token;
          sessionStorage.setItem('token', tokenStr);
          return userData;
        })
      );
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    const user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    console.log(!(user === null));
    return !(user === null);
  }

  getUser() {
    const user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    return user;
  }

  logOut() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
  }
}
```

**header.component.html**

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span><a mat-button href="http://www.conexiona.com" style="font-size: larger;">Conexiona Web Client - Crmiguez</a></span>
    <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <span class="align-center"></span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <a mat-button *ngIf="!loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/login" class="nav-link">Login</a>
    <a mat-button *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/" class="nav-link">View Users</a>
    <a mat-button *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" class="nav-link"> Welcome, {{ loginService.getUser() }} !</a>
    <a mat-button *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/logout" class="nav-link">LogOut</a>

  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *ngIf

```
<button *ngIf="user.userName==loginService.getUser()" class="btn btn-danger"  (click)="deleteUser(user)"> Delete user</button>
```

The condition seems to be correct, but I recommend you to console log `user.userName` and `loginService.getUser()` in order to see if they are actually the same.

Comment: I edited your answer, it's the opposite different from current user. Yet, thanks so much for help me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a directive to hide elements, depending on logged in state, and role. This could be modifed:

```
export class RoleShowDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private hasView = false;
  private roles: string[];
  private loggedInSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }

  @Input() set appRoleShow(roles: string[]) {
    this.roles = roles;
    // this.evaluate();  //This is not needed as authStatusEvent is emitting on page load
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.loggedInSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loggedInSubscription = this.authorizationService.authStatusEvent.subscribe(loggedIn => {
      this.evaluate();
    });
  }

  evaluate() {
    if (!this.authorizationService.UserLoggedIn) {
      this.hide();
      return;
    }
    if (this.authorizationService.UserRole === 'Administrator') {
      this.show();
    } else if (this.roles && this.roles.indexOf(this.authorizationService.UserRole) !== -1) {
      this.show();
    } else {
      this.hide();
    }

  }

  show() {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    this.hasView = true;
  }

  hide() {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    this.hasView = false;

  }
}
```

The `loggedInSubscription` is merely an event that my Auth service emits when the user logs in /out

This can be used on any element, by giving it the role it should show for:

```
<li class="nav-item active" ngbDropdown *appRoleShow="['User']">
```

Comment: I see that you mean. Auth is right option, but in case of JWT, what would it be? Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Are you gonna use roles, or is it only important that the user is logged in? JWT shouldn't mean anything, when you have your authentication service that handles that for you.

Comment: Only logged in, but your answer suits for next steps in other projects I am take part of. Thanks again.

Comment: Great. Otherwise just remove the need for role, and it should work.